# How to combine two List<Object[]> objects into a single List<Object[]>

Tags: java, list

I have two `List<Object[]>`s.

The first one has elements like `{1, 'a'}, {2, 'd'}`, etc...  That's the `Object[]` here is always an array of two `Object`s (`Integer` and `Character`).

The second one has `{1, 12.0}, {2, 14.0}`, etc.. The `Object[]` here is an array of two `Object`'s (`Integer` and `Double`).

`Integer`s  from the first list are absolutely the same to the `Integer`s from the second List. I mean, for any list element `e` from the first list there is an element `ee` from the second list such that `e[0] == ee[0]`. And vice versa.

I need to construct a `List<Object[]>` from the two `List<Object[]>`s such that the `List<Object[]>` has to contain elements like `{1, 'a', 12.0}, {2, 'd', 14.0}`, etc...

How can I do that?

Maybe there's an instant solution from the `apache commons` or `google guava` libraries?

**A tiny note**: The lists are returned by the `criteria.list()` method in hibernate.

Comment: Is it OK to use java 8?

Comment: This seems like a simple enough problem to quickly code out using "classical means", I'm sure that from there it's going to be a lot easier to find ways to improve your code.

Comment: You should use this situation to avoid object arrays completely and to use a model class instead. This model class would hold 3 instance variables of type `int`, `char` and `double`. Your array is like a "surprise bag" and since it could contain anything, it should be avoided.

Comment: @Bohemian No, In our production environment we're using Java 5. But it'd also be good if you demonstrated how to do it with Java 8.

Comment: @Tom I'm not sure if it possible. I have two completely different entities which I can't join together.

Comment: @Tom Ah, right. I didn't read the question.

Comment: @St.Antario If you want to merge them, then one model class could contain a method `#with(otherEntity)` that will return a new instance of the new model class that contains the data of both "source" instances. And since you want to merge these two object array, these scenario with 3 model classes should be possible.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work

```
Map<Integer, Character> map1 = new HashMap<Integer, Character>();
for (Object[] o : list1) {
    map1.put((Integer)o[0], (Character)o[1]);
}

Map<Integer, Double> map2 = new HashMap<Integer, Double>();
for (Object[] o : list2) {
    map2.put((Integer)o[0], (Double)o[1]);
}

List<Object[]> list3 = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
    list3.add(new Object[] { i, map1.get(i), map2.get(i) })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In any solution, I would first create a map of the second list, and look that up while iterating over the first list.

In java 8, it's reasonably neat (2 lines):

```
final Map<Integer, Double> map = list2.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a[0], a -> a[1]));
List<Object[]> result = list1.stream()
    .map(a -> new Object{a[0], a[1], map.get(a[0])})
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note: code not tested and no IDE used (thumbed on phone), so there could be errors.